# Angular- Use $cookies at route js page

Tags: angularjs, cookies, routes

I'm trying to use $cookies in route js page, is there anyway to use this in route? I have $cookies.get('token') in route js page but got error. I have put $cookies inside function. Is there anything I missing, or is $cookies can't use in route js?

codes:

```
 /* VIEW LOADS HERE */
 MainCtrl.config([ '$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider','$locationProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $cookies){

  // Redirect any unmatched URL
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');


  // $cookies.get('token');
  if(1==1){
    // Checkout : Sign In
    $stateProvider
    .state('checkout-signin', { 
      url: '/checkout/signin',
      templateUrl: 'app/views/checkout.signin.html',
      controller: 'CartFormController',
      resolve: {
        deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
          return $ocLazyLoad.load({
            name: 'MainCtrl',  
            files: [
              'app/controllers/cart-form.controller.js'
            ]                    
          });
        }]
      }
    })
  }
}]);
```

thanks!

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: when i uncomment code `$cookies.get('token');`, I get this error

`angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module`

Comment: Then issue is not with the cookies, its with your module.post your module declaration

Comment: so then how to solve this, I really new with Angular. what should I add?

Comment: I am worried if my manager not allow me to teamviewer

Comment: post your module code here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134137/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-fai-zal-dong).